# single layer net in keras with imagedatagenerator, but loss is always negative

Tags: image, keras, neural-network, deep-learning, loss-function

I have tried many kinds of net, but even in basic net(single layer), loss which set as binary_crossentropy is always negative

here is the code

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
import os
import cv2
from PIL import ImageFile

ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
train_path = 'D:/rectangle'
val_path = 'D:/rectang'

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, 1, 1, input_shape=(230, 230, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
          optimizer='rmsprop',
          metrics=['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
            samplewise_center=True,
            samplewise_std_normalization=True)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(230, 230),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')
validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=(230, 230),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='binary')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=200,
    epochs=50,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=800
)
```

here is the processing:
  1/200 [..............................] - 
ETA: 20:17 - loss: 12.9030 - acc: 0.1250
  2/200 [..............................] - 
ETA: 10:22 - loss: -2.0179 - acc: 0.0625
  3/200 [..............................] - 
ETA: 7:03 - loss: -6.3273 - acc: 0.0417 
  4/200 [..............................] - 
ETA: 5:23 - loss: -7.8592 - acc: 0.0312
  5/200 [..............................] - 
ETA: 4:24 - loss: -8.6776 - acc: 0.0250
  6/200 [..............................] - 
ETA: 3:44 - loss: -9.5563 - acc: 0.0208
  7/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 3:15 - loss: -9.3298 - acc: 0.0179
  8/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 2:54 - loss: -9.3455 - acc: 0.0156
  9/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 2:37 - loss: -10.2439 - acc: 0.0139
 10/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 2:24 - loss: -10.5647 - acc: 0.0125
 11/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 2:13 - loss: -10.8719 - acc: 0.0114
 12/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 2:04 - loss: -11.3775 - acc: 0.0104
 13/200 [>.............................] - 
ETA: 1:56 - loss: -11.3066 - acc: 0.0096
 14/200 [=>............................] - 
ETA: 1:49 - loss: -11.4598 - acc: 0.0089
 15/200 [=>............................] - 
ETA: 1:48 - loss: -11.4930 - acc: 0.0083
 16/200 [=>............................] - 
ETA: 1:47 - loss: -11.6465 - acc: 0.0078
 17/200 [=>............................] - 
ETA: 1:51 - loss: -11.6061 - acc: 0.0074

the input image is the photo of breast cancer hispological images, with 460*460 size and 20000 pics in PNG format.
I would appreciate it if it will be solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are doing a binary classification (based in your loss), your last activation function should be sigmoid. So 
instead of

`model.add(Dense(1))`

your last layer should look like:

`model.add(Dense(1,activation='sigmoid'))`

Without specifying it, your activation will be just linear by default, which fits a regression senario rather than classification.

Comment: Thanks for your advise.   Actually, I delete some layers of net for a try. It used to be a 5-layer-conv2d net, and the last layer is truly the fully connected layer with sigmoid. I add it just now, but nothing changed...

Comment: And thank you again, that's the problem caused by my data classification.